# TypeError: firebase.loadStorageRules() is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm writing unit tests for the Firebase Storage security rules and when attempting to run the mocha test I get this error:

> TypeError: firebase.loadStorageRules() is not a function

For some reason the functions related specifically to Storage rules are not recognized even though it is in the documentation i'm using:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests#rut-v1-testing

It should be noted that the firstore db rules functions (ex. loadFirestoreRules() )are recognized and those tests do work.

I'm thinking it must be a dependency issue, and I have tried updating the related packages but it's still not working. I'm using js v8 sdk with the following dependencies:

```
"firebase-admin": "^8.9.2",
"firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
"@firebase/testing": "^0.20.11"
"firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.7"
```

Comment: Are you using a firestore database or a realtime database?